# Nginx HTTP & HTTPS Configs: Redirect SOME URLs

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, nginx, https

I have just relaunched a Wordpress site on Nginx, serving content over `HTTP`. At present we are not looking to migrate the entire site to `HTTPS`, however the old version of the site had pages at `https://store.website.com`.

Now the new versions of those old pages (for instance, `https://store.website.com/category/this-product.html`, or, `https://store.website.com/that-product.html`) live at `http://www.website.com/store/category/this-product/`.

We have lots of links in about 10,000 posts to the `HTTPS` pages, so for us right now instead of changing all of those links in our posts, it makes the most sense to simply redirect those `https://store....` pages to the new `http` page.

I have a full list of the URLs of the old `HTTPS` pages that we want to redirect. We are still loading a number of products in to the new website (there are about 100 there), and still need to load in another 900 or so. Therefore, we will be using 301 redirects for some URLs (the products already loaded), and 302 redirects to the top level category page for the remainder of the products that still need to be loaded. Once those new products are loaded, we will change the 302 redirect from the top-level category page, to be a 301 redirect to the permanent home.

I have only ever setup `HTTP` servers in Nginx, so here are my questions:

1. I am not sure if creating an HTTPS server will create a duplicate content for each post or not, by making the content available via two protocols
2. How close am I with the config below to accomplishing what I have described? Note: below you will first find my `HTTP` Nginx config, and below the `HTTPS` Nginx config.

*********HTTP NGINX CONFIG*********

```
    server {
            listen   80;

            access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

            root /var/www;
            index index.php;

            server_name website.com www.website.com;

            client_max_body_size 100M;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                    #auth_basic "Admin Login";
                    #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;

            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    # With php5-fpm:
                    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
            }
            # BEGIN W3TC CDN
            location ~ \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$ {
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            }
            # END W3TC CDN
            #Yoast sitemap
            location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*)\.x(m|s)l$ {
                    rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
                    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
                    rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
                    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
                    access_log off;
            }
            # Example of the style of single-page redirects we are currently using
            location = /this-page/ { return 301 /store/category/that-page/; }
    }
```

*********HTTPS NGINX CONFIG*********

```
    server {
           listen 443;
           server_name store.website.com;

           root /var/www;
           index index.php;

           ssl on;
           ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
           ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

           ssl_session_timeout 10m;

           ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
           ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
           ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

           location / {
                   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
    }
```

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating a new config that listens to your old site URL and create a rewrite rule to redirect to the new site.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

UPDATE 1:

```
server {
       listen 443;
       server_name store.website.com;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

       ssl_session_timeout 10m;

       ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       # To rewrite URLs like https://store.website.com/category/this-product.html
       rewrite ^/category/(.*).html$  http://www.website.com/store/category/$1 permanent;

       # To rewrite URLs like https://store.website.com/that-product.html
       rewrite ^/(.*).html$  http://www.website.com/store/category/$1 permanent;

       # To rewrite URLs like https://store.website.com/abcasc/q343f/3f3/f3
       rewrite ^(.*) http://www.website.com$1 permanent; 
}
```

Not tested. But feel free to experiment.

Comment: Well I figured that much, unless I'm mistaken that's what I've shown that I'm trying to figure out above. This doesn't really even swing at answering my question.

Comment: From what I see, your configs above does not indicate any listening on store.website.com.

Comment: Good catch. Edited. Did you notice the two questions I mentioned about duplicate content and general suitability of the configs for what I described?

Comment: Yes I did. If you use the rewrite directive in your HTTPS config, i don't think it will create duplicate content because it redirects to the location that you want. I'm recommending you rewrite all url from store.website.com to www.website.com.

Comment: server {
 listen 443;
     server_name  store.website.com;

     rewrite ^(.*) `http://www.website.com$1` permanent;
}

Comment: Well the issue with that approach (if I understand correctly) is that it assumes the old HTTPS location is exactly the same as the new HTTP location. This is not the case. See second paragraph of question for details on this.

Comment: I think the same concept applies. Just need to figure out the pattern before and after the rewrite. Let me modify my answers above in a short while and see whether it can trigger something for a start.

Comment: Modified my answer. Feel free to experiment.

Comment: Ok, had a change to test this finally. I decided to start simple and use the config you provided above, but without the 'rewrite' blocks, and simply using 'location = /old/ssl/url { return 301 http://www.website.com/new/url/here; }'

While that did successfully redirect that URL, it also created 100% duplicate content at all other URLs, as I was concerned about.

How can I modify the config to only listen for the URLs I specify?